# How to use svn+ssh in IntelliJ Windows?

Tags: windows, svn, intellij-idea, ssh

Our SVN server allows ssh connections only. How can I configure IntelliJ on Windows to connect to SVN server using svn+ssh?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In order to connect to SVN using ssh on a Windows machine, you will need to

1. Generate your ssh private key and upload it to your user allowed keys on the server.
2. Create a saved PuTTy session to use the private key file.
3. Download TortoiseSVN Plink to be used as SSH tunnel.
4. Configure IntelliJ to use TortoiseSVN to connect to your SVN server.

Here are the details of these steps.

## 1. Generate your private key.

You can use [PUTTYGEN](https://www.ssh.com/ssh/putty/windows/puttygen) to generate the private key.

[image: Generate the private key]

Then save the key in the `.ssh` folder in the user home directory.

[image: save the key]

If you have Windows 10, you can use Bash on Ubuntu on Windows to generate and load your private keys.

```
ssh-keygen -t rsa
```

This will generate the file  `~/.ssh/id_rsa`

Then load the key to the server

```
ssh-copy-id  amr@example.com
```

The final step is to move the generated file from the Ubuntu subsystem path to your home directory in windows.

```
cp ~/.ssh/id_rsa  /mnt/c/Users/amr/.ssh/
```

You still need to convert the key from `OpenSSH` to `PPK` format using the PUTTYGEN tool. From the tool load the file and then save the private key again in the PPK format.

## 2. Create a saved PuTTy session and configure it to use your private key.

Create a new session in PuTTY for login into the SVN server and change the setting of SSH/Auth to point to the private key file

[image]

## 3. Use Tortoise SVN Plink as the ssh tunnel

Download and install [Tortoise SVN](https://tortoisesvn.net/downloads.html). It has a command line tool named `TortoisePlink` which is based on puTTY. We will use `plink` as the SSH tunnel for SVN.

## 4. Configure IntelliJ to use this SSH tunnel for Subversion.

Go to File/Settings/Version Control/Subversion then select SSH settings tab.
Select `Subversion config`

[image: intellij]

make sure SSH tunnel is set to `$SVN_SSH ssh -q`
then add the path to TortoisPlink as in the picture. Make sure to skip backslashes.

Then, you are good to go.

Comment: How do you change the `SVN_SSH:` field? I cannot type in there for some reason. I know where my `TortoisePlink.exe` sits but I can't set it there. Is that done somewhere else?

Comment: The SVN_SSH field is an OS environment variable.  Close IntelliJ, add the SVN_SSH variable, and reopen IntelliJ.  The field will be populated.