# How to use svn+ssh in PhpStorm Linux?

Tags: svn, ssh, phpstorm, private-key

I'm not able to update my SVN project, which is only accessible via SSH using private key.

In my project settings (Version Control > Subversion > SSH) **`Subversion config`** is enabled and I entered **`ssh -i /home/user/privateKey -p 222`**

This is not going to work, I'm always prompted for username and password. I can connect via **`ssh host`** and I'm connected.

So what do I have to to now? I read something about setting up the `SVN_SSH` Variable but I found only help for this when using windows... (see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44911174/how-to-use-svnssh-in-intellij-windows)).

In [this post](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-118615) the `svn config` file is mentioned. There I have this line

`ssh = ssh -i /home/user/privateKey -p 222`

But it still not working.

Answer (score 0):

Works for me with the described settings - [image]

Make sure Interactive mode is enabled and URL you are connecting to includes username.

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately this didn't work for me. Did you edit something in your subversion config file? Something like `ssh = $SVN_SSH...`? PhpStorm telles me to remove `-q` option from my subversion config. But I didn't set this option. Which distro do you use? Did you install subversion from distro repostitory?

Comment: I am on Mac, but I believe it should work the same way on linux. I did edit the subversion config and set `ssh = ssh -i /Users/dsmirnov/.ssh/pass -p 2222` there.