# Subversion SSH Tunnel issues

Tags: intellij-idea, ssh, svn, tortoisesvn, ssh-tunnel

I have been trying to connect to my SVN Server via Subversion and using [How to use svn+ssh in IntelliJ Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44911174/how-to-use-svnssh-in-intellij-windows/44911175#44911175) I have been trying to configure Intellij to use the SSH Tunnel, but it hasn't worked on my end.

I have followed the instructions by entering the following key:
[image: Intellij Subversion config]
Yet it can't find the `TortoisePlink.exe` file. In the comments section, it was mentioned,
that you have to create an environment variable that will then fill in the space.

I have done that, but without prevailing:

```
Variable name: $SVN_SSH ssh -q
Variable value: C:\Programe Files\TortoiseSVN\TortoisePlink.exe
```

Have I missed something or do I have to do any additional steps?

Comment: Have you filled everything according to: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/settings-version-control-subversion.html#Subversion_SSH_settings ?

What is the error you get?

Comment: Is `C:\Programe Files` with an `e` after `Program` a valid path on your machine?

Comment: No it isn't. Yes changed the location of the ToroiseSVN directory to "C:\TortoiseSVN\bin\svn.exe" and I don't get the error anymore, I stays on loading and doesn't load up the project. Any Idea what it could be?